# how to set dropdown default value using angularjs

Tags: angularjs

please refer the below fiddle
http://jsfiddle.net/nq1eyj1v/117/

can any one help how to set default option value as "Select"
Select on load ?

HTML:

```
<div ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="MyCtrl">
   <div class="col-xs-12">
      <label class="col-xs-6 control-label">Type:</label>
      <div class="col-xs-6">
         <select name="type" ng-model="payment.type" ng-dropdown required ng-change="changeme()" >
            <option ng-option value="Default">Select</option>
            <option ng-option value="Cash">Cash</option>
            <option ng-option value="Check">Check</option>
            <option ng-option value="Money Order">Money Order</option> 
         </select>
      </div>
   </div>

   <div class="col-xs-12"  ng-if="payment.type == 'Cash'">
     11111111111111
    </div>

    <div class="col-xs-12" ng-if="payment.type == 'Check'">
    22222222222
    </div>

    <div class="col-xs-12"  ng-if="payment.type == 'Money Order'">
     3333333333333
    </div>

</div>
```

Comment: `$scope.payment = { type : 'Cash' }` this will give you Cash as a default selected value.

Comment: In your controller - `$scope.payment.type = 'Default';`

Comment: If i set on my controller, bydefault value is loading, but my select option change is not working. that is on change on option ng-if content is not loading. any clue ?

Comment: change you this line  <option ng-option value="Default">Select</option>   to this   <option ng-option value="">Select</option>   :p

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I've update your JSFiddle [here.](http://jsfiddle.net/nq1eyj1v/120/)

I replaced the `options` using `ng-options`.

**HTML**

```
<div ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="MyCtrl">
    <div class="col-xs-12">
        <label class="col-xs-6 control-label">Type:</label>
            <div class="col-xs-6">
                <select name="type" ng-model="payment"
                    ng-dropdown required 
                    ng-change="changeme()"
                    ng-options="option.type for option in options">
                </select>
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="col-xs-12"  ng-if="payment.type == 'Cash'">
            11111111111111
        </div>

        <div class="col-xs-12" ng-if="payment.type == 'Check'">
            22222222222
        </div>

        <div class="col-xs-12" ng-if="payment.type == 'Money Order'">
            3333333333333
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

**JS**

```
var myApp = angular.module('myApp',[]);

function MyCtrl($scope) {
    $scope.options = [
        { type: 'Select' },
        { type: 'Cash' },
        { type: 'Check' },
        { type: 'Money Order' }
    ];

    $scope.payment = $scope.options[0];
}
```

As you can see, I initialized the `$scope.payment.type` value as `'Select'` by assigning it the first `$scope.options` value.

Comment: fine, but how to we can show different container on change of different value ? The fiddle you updated by default select is getting by the on change showing different div content is not working...!!

Answer (score 1):

Very easy. Just add empty value inside option.

```
<option value="">Select</option>
```

Finally :

```
 <select name="type" ng-model="payment.type" ng-dropdown required ng-change="changeme()" >
            <option ng-option value="">Select</option>
            <option ng-option value="Cash">Cash</option>
            <option ng-option value="Check">Check</option>
            <option ng-option value="Money Order">Money Order</option> 
         </select>
```

Updated Fiddle:  http://jsfiddle.net/nq1eyj1v/118/

EDIT 1 :

```
<div ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="MyCtrl">
   <div class="col-xs-12">
      <label class="col-xs-6 control-label">Type:</label>
      <div class="col-xs-6">
         <select name="type" ng-model="payment"  ng-dropdown required ng-change="changeme(payment)" ng-options="option.name for option in options"> 
              <option ng-option value="">Select</option>
         </select>
      </div>
   </div>

   <div class="col-xs-12"  ng-if="payment.name == 'Cash'">
     11111111111111
    </div>

    <div class="col-xs-12" ng-if="payment.name == 'Check'">
    22222222222
    </div>

    <div class="col-xs-12"  ng-if="payment.name == 'Money Order'">
     3333333333333
    </div>

</div>
```

JS:

```
var myApp = angular.module('myApp',[]);


function MyCtrl($scope) {
    $scope.options = [
        { name: 'Cash' },
        { name: 'Check' },
        { name: 'Money Order' }
    ];

    $scope.changeme = function (payment) {
       alert(payment.name)
    }

}
```

FIDDLE: http://jsfiddle.net/nq1eyj1v/121/

Comment: For that it better to go with angular ng-options.

Comment: i am using ng-options only but how to check the option value in "ng-if"  on my div to show or hide ?

Comment: If you're satisfied with an answer, don't forget to upvote it, and select it as an answer.

Answer (score 0):

You have to set `payment.type` to `"Default"` in your controller.

```
myApp.controller( 'MyCtrl', function( $scope, ...) {
    $scope.payment = ...;
    $scope.payment.type = "Default";
    ...
}
```

Comment: If i set on my controller, bydefault value is loading, but my select option change is not working. that is on change on option ng-if content is not loading. any clue ?

Comment: I've updated your Fiddle and it works : http://jsfiddle.net/nq1eyj1v/124/
You were not using a correct syntax to declare your controller.

Answer (score 0):

```
function MyCtrl($scope) {

$scope.payment.type="Default";
// payment.type = 'Check' ;
// $scope.changeme = function() {
// alert('here');

 }
```

Modify your js code by this

Answer (score 0):

Just Change Your

```
<option ng-option value="Default">Select</option>
```

to

```
<option ng-option value="">Select</option>
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
var app = angular.module('MyApp', [])
        app.controller('MyController', function ($scope) {
            $scope.payments= [{
                Id: 0,
                Name: 'Select'
            }, {
                Id: 1,
                Name: 'Cash'
            },{
                Id: 2,
                Name: 'Check'
            },{
                Id: 3,
                Name: 'Money Order'
            }];
        });
```

```html
 <script type="text/javascript" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.3.9/angular.min.js"></script>
 <div ng-app="MyApp">
<div ng-controller="MyController">

<h2>Using ng-selected with payment id</h2><br>
    <select ng-model="drp">
        <option ng-repeat="payment in payments" value="{{payment.Id}}"
                ng-selected="{{ payment.Id== 0}}">
            {{payment.Name}}
        </option>
    </select>
    <br>
  <h2> Using ng-selected with payment Name</h2><br>
    <select ng-model="drp">
        <option ng-repeat="payment in payments" value="{{payment.Id}}"
                ng-selected="{{ payment.Name== 'Cash'}}">
            {{payment.Name}}
        </option>
    </select> 
</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
Following code set the default value of dropdown

In Html:
<select name="type" ng-model="payment.type" ng-dropdown required >
    <option ng-option value="Default">Select</option>
    <option ng-option value="Cash">Cash</option>
    <option ng-option value="Check">Check</option>
    <option ng-option value="Money Order">Money Order</option> 
 </select>


In angular controller:

$scope.payment.type = 'Default';
```