# How to set default value to dropdownlist in angularjs

Tags: javascript, angularjs

hi I am developing web application in angularjs. I have one dropdownlistbox with some values. Below is my dropdownlistbox html code.

```
<select id="calc-year" ng-model="period" name="period" required range-numberddwn="rangeddwn">
   <option value="" label="{{ 'Month' | translate }}">{{ 'Month' | translate }}</option>
   <option ng-repeat="x in cal" value="{{x.Period}}">{{x.Period}} {{'Months' | translate}}</option>
</select>
```

Below is my code to assign values to dropdownlistbox.

```
$scope.cal = response.data.data.Period;
```

Below is the screenshot of data i am assigning to cal.

[image: Dropdown values]

If i want to set 4th value by default then i tried as below.

`$scope.period = $scope.cal[4]; and $scope.period = response.data.data.Period[4];`

Whenever i set as above i blank value will come in dropdownlist

Above both options did not work out for me. May i know what is the solution to set default value? Any help would be appreciated. Thank you.

Comment: use `ng-init` for set default value

Comment: Thank you i want to assign it in controller.

Comment: then you have to use ng-options ,look this :https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngOptions

Comment: Possible duplicate of [how to set dropdown default value using angularjs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35743472/how-to-set-dropdown-default-value-using-angularjs)

Comment: The problem can be caused by fact, that you mixed `option ng-repeat` and separate `option value=`, try to merge them into the one `option ng-repeat`

Comment: thanks Slava. May i get some example in order to fix this

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your controller, set a value in scope variable which you want to be the default value for your drop down. Make sure, cal variable exist in scope. Then try something like this,

```
$scope.calValue = $scope.cal[3]; //This will be Default cal value
```

Then in your view(html), use ng-options something like this,

```
<select ng-model="calValue" ng-options="x.Period for x in cal"></select>
```

Now, calValue will be the default value in drop down, and if you select any other option from dropdown, then that will become the value of calValue.

Cheers !!

Comment: You saved my day. Thanks

Comment: also i want to know instead of setting using index like $scope.cal[3] how can i set using value?

Comment: Iterate over the array/list (using loop), compare your required value in array element`s values (using if-else), and as per the outcome of comparison assign that array element to default value. You can write this code in controller itself.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to set the 4th value index should be 3

```
 $scope.period = $scope.cal[3]; 
 $scope.period = response.data.data.Period[3];
```

Comment: Thanks but i just gave example but problem is i am not able to set any of the values. Whenever i set $scope.period = $scope.cal[3];  i get blank in dropdownlistbox.